# C# excel format Condition

Tags: c#, office-interop

I am trying to use Excel conditional formatting in C#.  Below is the code:

```
Excel.Range rangeFormat = ws.get_Range("F1", "F1");
Excel.FormatConditions fcs = range.FormatConditions;
Excel.FormatCondition fc = (Excel.FormatCondition)fcs.Add
    (Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, Type.Missing, "=IF($F$1) >= 10", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
Excel.Interior interior = fc.Interior;
interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.Red);
interior = null;
fc = null;
fcs = null;
```

However, I am getting a `ParameterCountException` but I am sure that I have given it the correct number of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN Suggests that `Excel.FormatCondition.Add` takes up to 4 arguments

```
FormatCondition Add(
    [In] XlFormatConditionType Type, 
    [In, Optional] object Operator, 
    [In, Optional] object Formula1, 
    [In, Optional] object Formula2
);
```

You could try typing it as:

```
Excel.FormatCondition fc = (Excel.FormatCondition)fcs.Add(
    Type: Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression,
    Formula1: "=IF($F$1) >= 10"
);
```

Although the Formula your using looks like it might be incorrect too. I think you probalby want `=$F$1 >= 10`, although in that case you should also be able to use:

```
Excel.FormatCondition fc = (Excel.FormatCondition)fcs.Add(
    Type: Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression,
    Operator: Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlGreaterEqual
    Formula1: "10"
);
```